# How to prove the equivalence of these optimization problems?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I am reading some lecture notes and in one procedure step it is stated that:
$$\min_{\mathbf{x}}\; \langle \mathbf{H}, \mathbf{Rx-Z}\rangle + \frac{\lambda}{2} \|\mathbf{Rx-Z}\|_F^2$$
is equivalent to
$$\min_{\mathbf{x}}\; \frac{\lambda}{2}\|\mathbf{Rx-Z}+\frac{\mathbf{H}}{\lambda}\|_F^2,$$
where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbf{H}, \mathbf{Z}\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{2N}$ and $\mathbf{R}: \mathbb{R}^{2N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ is a linear operator that converts a vector into a Hankel matrix.

I am trying to derive that equality by rewriting the expression into trace operators but I can not prove the equivalence. Any idea about how to prove the statement?

Thanks.

Comment: You can write $\| \mathbf{Rx} - \mathbf{Z} + \frac{\mathbf{H}}{\lambda} \|^2_F$ as $\langle \mathbf{Rx} - \mathbf{Z} + \frac{\mathbf{H}}{\lambda},  \mathbf{Rx} - \mathbf{Z} + \frac{\mathbf{H}}{\lambda} \rangle$.  Once you expand this latter expression, you will get what you need.

Comment: When you write \text{min}_{\mathbf{x}} then you see $\displaystyle \text{min}_{\mathbf{x}}$, but when you write \min_{\mathbf{x}}, then (at least in a "displayed" as opposed to "inline" context) you see $\displaystyle \min_{\mathbf{x}}$.  The latter usage also results in proper spacing in things like $A\min B$ and $A\min(B)$, and is standard. (I edited the question accordingly.) $\qquad$

Comment: @Shagnik Thanks for the suggestion but after expanding I get original terms plus one more term $\text{trace}(\frac{\mathbf{H}^*\mathbf{H}}{\lambda^2}) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\|\mathbf{H}\|_F^2$ that I do not know where to fit in the original expression. Any idea?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for editing the question! :)

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\|\mathbf{H}\|_F^2$ is a constant independent of $\mathbf{x}$, it simply translates the values of the objective function, and does not affect where the minimum occurs.

Comment: @Shagnik That was the point, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two minimization problems are *equivalent* in the sense that the minimizers are the same

$$\arg\min_{\mathrm x} \left\{ \langle \mathrm H, \mathrm R(\mathrm x) - \mathrm Z\rangle + \frac{\lambda}{2} \|\mathrm R (\mathrm x) - \mathrm Z\|_F^2 \right\} = \arg\min_{\mathrm x} \left\{ \frac{\lambda}{2} \bigg\| \mathrm R(\mathrm x) - \mathrm Z + \frac{\mathrm H}{\lambda} \bigg\|_F^2\right\}$$

However, the minima are **not** the same, as

$$\min_{\mathrm x} \left\{ \langle \mathrm H, \mathrm R(\mathrm x) - \mathrm Z\rangle + \frac{\lambda}{2} \|\mathrm R(\mathrm x) - \mathrm Z\|_F^2 \right\} = \min_{\mathrm x} \left\{ \frac{\lambda}{2} \bigg\| \mathrm R(\mathrm x) - \mathrm Z + \frac{\mathrm H}{\lambda} \bigg\|_F^2\right\} - \frac{1}{2\lambda} \|\mathrm H\|_F^2$$

Comment: That was the key point, as @Shagnik commented the term $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\|\mathbf{H}\|_F^2$ is constant and therefore the minimizer does not change.